# There was a problem with order creation. Notice: Array to string conversion in /vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php

Tags: magento2.3

I have received this error only once. The customer tried to place an order using afterpay payment method and afterpay approved the payment but while creating order in Magento it threw this error:

> There was a problem with order creation. Notice: Array to string
>   conversion in /vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on
>   line 3088

The problem is I cannot reproduce it again. How do I fix this?

Is this a core bug?

Comment: No , it seems while placing an order, someone run magento 2 commands, thats why you might see the error and won't reproduce it again.

Comment: @DineshRajput I have not run any magento 2 commands in that time period.